# Why do I find `/*{{{*/` and `/*}}}*/` around functions in C code?

Tags: c

I have recently taken over maintaining a C code, that is managed using GNU tools (automake, configure, gcc). Around all code blocks I find a comment with three curly braces such as `/*{{{*/` and `/*}}}*/`. Why?
Is this related to some pre-processing macro?

Here is an example:

```
int dump_rayfile (char *file) /*{{{*/
{
   FILE *fp;

   ... other stuff with the file...

   fclose (fp);
   return 0;
}

/*}}}*/
```

I've tried to google this question, but unfortunately searching for it is very difficult because most search engines try to interpret all the special characters in `/*{{{*/*` in some fancy way instead of searching for it literally.

Comment: It might be `fdm` marker for Vim, when one preferes manual folding method.

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate.  Next time try searching google for "Three curly brackets" rather than the symbols.

Comment: I learned about [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%2F*{{{*%2F) from someone else on this site. Searching for `/*{{{*/` makes it look like this has to do with Vim somehow.

Comment: I in fact searched for different combinations of "triple curly braces c code" with little success. I appreciate that "three" may have been better than "triple".

Comment: I would accept to close this as a duplicate (the php question is close enough), but I cannot do so myself.